# C - Max Number From Unknown Number Of Numbers

Tags: c, matrix, max

Here i am again, asking for your help.

I'll ask question below, here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    int matrix[10][10];
    int nrows, ncols, i, j, tmp, rsum, smax;

    printf("Enter number of rows: "); //user enters number of rows
    scanf("%d", &nrows);
    if(nrows < 2){
        printf("\n Out of range, please try again");
        exit(5);
    }

    printf("Enter number of columns: "); //user enters number of columns
    scanf("%d", &ncols);
    if(ncols < 2){
        printf("\n Out of range, please try again");
        exit(5);
    }

    printf("Enter matrix elements: "); //user enters all the elements for Matrix
    //Run over every element + ONLY POSITIVE LOOP
    for(i = 0; i < nrows; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < ncols; j++){
            tmp=0;
            scanf("%d",&tmp);
            while(tmp<0){
                printf("Only Positive Numbers!!!\n");
                scanf("%d",&tmp);
            }
            matrix[i][j]=tmp;
        }
    }

    //Print finished matrix
    printf("This is your matrix: \n");
    for(i = 0; i < nrows; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < ncols; j++){
            printf("%d \t",matrix[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    //Print sum of each row
    for(i=0; i<nrows; i++){
        rsum = 0;
        for(j=0; j<ncols; j++){
            rsum += matrix[i][j];
        }
        printf("\nSum of elements of Row %d = %d\n", i+1, rsum);
    }

    //print row with highest sum

    return 0;
}
```

So, i have matrix and have some tasks to do, restriction for user to enter only positive numbers, sum of each of the rows, etc.
Now i need to find the biggest number from sums of rows, i don't know how many number i will have, i need something that will work with any amount of numbers.

Here is code output:

```
Enter Number Of Rows: 3
Enter Number of Columns: 3
Enter Elements: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

This Is Your Matrix:
1   2   3
4   5   6
7   8   9

Sum Of Elements Of Row 1 = 6
Sum Of Elements Of Row 2 = 15
Sum Of Elements Of Row 3 = 24
```

I want to check all the sums of rows and print out the biggest one, for the example above, something like this should be added to this output:

```
Row With Largest Sum [Row Number] = [Row Sum]
```

Waiting for your help.

Comment: So what is your problem? Seems to me you are on the right track.

Comment: What is it that makes that hard for you? Correct me if I'm wrong but couldn't you just create a variable `myMaximum` and whenever you print the row sum, overwrite that variable if the new row sum is larger?

Comment: I tried many things, but can't exactly find the best way, thing is that i can't find tutorials, only for arrays and changing the code is a bit difficult for the beginner like me

Comment: @lucidbrot I understand, i found many solutions, but can't finish the code normally, not that good in C yet.

Comment: @ლუკაჩიტიშვილი Then you should practice, not ask strangers on the internet to do your homework for you.

Comment: @Ivan It is not my homework, i am just practicing this language for Engineering, but after hours of working sometimes i stopped with such small things.

Comment: @ლუკაჩიტიშვილი It seems like you have already used everything that you need to achieve this. You know how to assign a variable. You know how to write an if statement (which you need to check if your new sum is larger than the stored one), and you know how to print the end result. I'll gladly help you if you can tell where _exactly_ the problem lies

Comment: And note that you don't check that the number of rows and columns is less than or equal to 10, if the user requests a larger matrix you are going to overrun the assigned storage with undefined results.

Comment: *"Waiting for your help."* - was that intended to be a question?  Everything you seem to need to finish this is already done in some form or another in other parts of the code. So, do what you did before, but a little differently.

Comment: From the words of the mouths of the wise, "which book are you reading?"...

Answer (score 0):

Define the matrix after you get the number of rows and columns, like this:

```
unsigned rows = 0;
unsigned columns = 0;

// Rows
printf("Number of rows: ");
scanf("%u", &rows);

// Columns
printf("Number of columns: ");
scanf("%u", &columns);

// Matrix
int matrix[rows][columns];
```